# Checking if the inputted name has special characters or number

Tags: java, char

I'm trying to show in this program that it checks every letter the user types. How can I avoid the program from displaying every time that it sees a special character or an integer? If it sees at least 1 error, the default name would be Mang Jose.

Example:

```
Enter name: james231 
output:  
james231
james231
james231
james231
james231
Mang Jose
Mang Jose
Mang Jose
```

Correct output should be:

```
Enter Name: james231
output:
Mang Jose
```

---

```
for(int i=0; i< name.length(); i++) {
  if(!(name.charAt(i) >='A' && name.charAt(i) <= 'Z' || name.charAt(i) >='a' && name.charAt(i) <= 'z' || name.charAt(i) == ' ')) {
    System.out.println("Name: Mang Jose");
  } else if(name.charAt(i) >='A' && name.charAt(i) <= 'Z' || name.charAt(i) >='a' && name.charAt(i) <= 'z' || name.charAt(i) == ' ') {
    System.out.println("\nName: "+name);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use methods from the `Character` class: `Character.isSpace()`, etc etc. That would make your program easier. Also, if you use Guava, consider `CharMatcher`. Finally, you can also use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an additional variable - let's call it `useDefaultName`. Before the loop you need to set it to `false` - you don't want to use the default name unless an error occurs. Then if anywhere in the loop an invalid character is found, you can simply set `useDefaultName` to `true` and `break` from the loop. After the loop, if `useDefaultName` is `true`. If so, `System.out.println("Name: Mang Jose");` else output `name`.

Your code will look like this:

```
boolean useDefaultName = false;
for(int i=0; i< name.length(); i++) 
{
    if(!(name.charAt(i) >='A' && name.charAt(i) <= 'Z' || name.charAt(i) >='a' && name.charAt(i) <= 'z' || name.charAt(i) == ' ')) 
    {
        useDefaultName = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (useDefaultName)
    System.out.println("Name: Mang Jose");
else
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
```

This should be good if you're trying to learn how to write code and want to do all of the basics yourself. Otherwise I'd suggest using regular expressions or patterns (see other answers).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you check your string char by char. The first five chars (`james`) are valid, so your code prints the `name` five times (once for each char), while the last three chars `231` are invalid, thus your code prints the default name.

So I'd go for some way to check your whole string at once and not char by char.

You may use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
String name = "james231"; //use your userinput here!

if(p.matcher(name).matches()) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
} else  {
    System.out.println("Name: Mang Jose");
}

//prints:
//Name: Mang Jose
```

[demo @ ideone](https://ideone.com/zpjdn2)

This way you check the whole string if it only contains letters (lowercase and uppercase). If this is the case it prints the given name, otherwise it prints the default name.

If you want to allow more characters, simply add them to the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
For example if you want to allow spaces, you change it to `[a-zA-Z ]`.